# Подсветка "несуществующих методов" (геттеры/сеттеры), которые заданы аннотациями, Spring, Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

Всем доброго времени суток. Вопрос следующего содержания: есть класс с аннотациями Spring

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
```

И когда я хочу воспользоваться геттерами/сеттерами, то код выделяется красным, будто эти функции не существуют, хотя они как бы есть и все работает, если не обращать внимание на подчеркивание

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно как-то отключить эти подчеркивания? Редактор кода - Intellij IDEA. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно:

1. установить плагин Lombok
2. ctrl + shift + S
3. В поиске вводишь annotation
4. Нужно установить чекбокс напротив фразы Enable annotation processing

Answer (score 2):

Добавь плагин Lombok в Идею и тогда все будет работать и в настройках Enable annotation processing